# How to merge/count adjacent 1's within an std:array using std?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, std

Let say I've an `std:array<int>` such as:

```
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

I'd like to use std (if possible) to do this in c++11:

- sum adjacent 1's
- erase the summed value
- transform 0 to 1

So getting this result for the example above:

```
1 3 1 2 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Is [this](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/335gQ1var30) what you are looking for? I'm not sure what you mean with `c++-11` -- is the hyphen to be interpreted as *less than*?

Comment: @trincot typo, edited.

Comment: @trincot seems correct and very efficient. I'm testing it. Add answer, quite sure you got accepted :) Thanks

Comment: I found "erase the summed value" confusing. I presume the first two steps are equivalent to replacing adjacent 1's with their sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could apply this logic with a single pass through the input values, while creating the result vector:

- If the current value is a 1, and also the previous value was a 1, then increment the last value that was already added to the result vector, which is a counter for adjacent 1-bits
- In all other cases, append a new entry to the result vector, which is the same as the current value, except that a 0 becomes 1. If we were reading a 0, then this is what we want, and if we were reading a 1, then this is the initial value of a counter that might get incremented in the next iterations. Anything else, like -1, is copied as-is.

As to `std::array`: as this is a fixed size data type, and the size of the result is unknown beforehand, I would use vectors instead. But I added the code to convert the array to a vector. If your requirements don't insist on `array`, you could of course have your input represented by a `std::vector` from the very start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> convert(std::vector<int> bin) {
    std::vector<int> v;
    bool prevWasOne = false;
    for (auto bit : bin) {
        if (bit == 1 && prevWasOne) { // Adjacent 1s?
            v.back()++;
        } else {
            v.push_back(bit ? bit : 1); // 0? Then 1, else copy value
        }
        prevWasOne = bit == 1;
    }
    return v;
}

// Example run:
int main() {
    std::array<int, 8> arr = {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0};
    // Convert array to vector
    std::vector<int> vec(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
    // Apply conversion
    std::vector<int> result = convert(vec);
    // Output the result
    for (auto val : result) {
        std::cout << val << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: hi! what if I need to introduce another state? such as: 0 => 1, 1 => summed adjacent, -1 => keep -1 (i.e. the new state)? let me know if you need another question, or you can just edit this one :)

Comment: Here's my attempt, but its not so "elegant": https://www.mycompiler.io/view/4dgGPhqwUmy

Comment: Alright, I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks dude! Similar to mine, but better :)